# Writing Excel file specifying Row and Column number - openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, xlwt, openpyxl

I have a code which had written with `XLWT` library and now I am switching to `openpyxl` because it allows `XLSX` files that has more Row limit than `XLWT` allows

I wrote the cells by specifying the row and column number in `XLWT`

```
worksheet.write(1, 2, "City")
```

Now I want to know how can I do this in `openpyxl`???
I have tried

```
worksheet.cell(1, 1).value = "test"
```

But I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "test"
```

Comment: Nice. I employed this sort of assignment in a loop, but got this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237229/why-is-the-iteration-over-this-loop-not-adding-cells-in-openpyxl. Any idea why?