# Why is the iteration over this loop not adding cells in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, openpyxl

Given the following as the contents of the first sheet of an xlsx roi.xlsx:

[image]

Then:

```
wb = load_workbook('roi.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws=wb.worksheets[0]
keynames = [i.value for i in ws.columns[0]]
```

I want to add **values** into column B from the following dict:

```
mydict = {'carnival': 2, 'festival': 3}
```

When I try:

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    keyPosition = keynames.index(k)
    ws.cell(row = keyPosition, column = 2).value = v
```

I end up with a new column B, but empty values throughout, **AND** when I go to re-open the file after saving it with wb.save, Excel can't open the file because it is corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using the index of `keynames` to store in the B column, index starts at 0 , but column `B` does not have any 0 row. You should ideally be getting - `openpyxl.utils.exceptions.CellCoordinatesException: There is no row 0 (B0)`

Try this code instead (to start changing values at row 1,instead of 0) -

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    keyPosition = keynames.index(k)
    ws.cell(row = keyPosition + 1, column = 2).value = v
```

Comment: `.index()` is pretty slow on lists. Better to create a dictionary of the format (key, row) for the lookup.